# SCSS style for select tag not working on mobile only

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

My web app has SCSS styling for inputs and select elements, but for some reason, the styling is not showing on mobile devices despite showing properly on computers. Does anyone know why that would be happening?  CSS code below

```
.text-input {
  background: $dark-grey;
  border: 1px solid $off-white;
  color: $off-white;
  font-size: $font-size-medium;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 auto $s-size auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: $s-size;
  width: 90rem;
}

.text-input::placeholder {
  color: $off-white;
}

.select {
  @extend .text-input;
}
```

Comment: Is that the whole CSS file? If not, can you check for @media queries in your CSS? Maybe there are rules that say apply only on screen larger than some number of pixels?

Comment: well, that's not css, it's a pre-processor, probably sass

Comment: It is SCSS.  I tried removing the variables and it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add webkit-appearance

```
 .text-input {
      background: $dark-grey;
      border: 1px solid $off-white;
      color: $off-white;
      font-size: $font-size-medium;
      font-weight: 300;
      margin: 0 auto $s-size auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      padding: $s-size;
      width: 90rem;
      -webkit-appearance:none; // add this to add custom design cross-browser
    }

    .text-input::placeholder {
      color: $off-white;
    }

    .select {
      @extend .text-input;
    }
```